How to concatenate lines from two text files using Java Streams
I have the following requirement (working with large text files):
Given sourceFile1, and sourceFile2, for each line in both files, concatenate the values (line by line) and put them in targetFile.
For example: calling FileMergerImpl.merge(sourceFile1,sourceFile2,targetFile, String::concat); on
sourceFile1:
Line1
Line2
Line3

sourceFile2:
A
B

Should result in:
targetFile:
Line1A
Line2B
Line3

Question: Can this be achieved solely using java streams (and specifically, using java.nio.file.Files)?
I thought of calling flatMap() on Stream.of(Files.lines(sourceFilename1), Files.lines(sourceFilename2)). The challenge is that I don't know how to concatenate the entries from each stream onto a single stream.
Here is my code solution, not using Java Streams:
package com.example.codingTest;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.util.function.BinaryOperator;

public class FileMergerImpl {

    public void merge(Path sourceFilename1, Path sourceFilename2, Path targetFilename, BinaryOperator<String> lineCombiner) {

        try (BufferedReader file1Reader = Files.newBufferedReader(sourceFilename1);
             BufferedReader file2Reader = Files.newBufferedReader(sourceFilename2);
             BufferedWriter targetFileWriter = Files.newBufferedWriter(targetFilename)) {

            boolean areThereLinesLeftToRead = true;
            while (areThereLinesLeftToRead) {
                String file1Line = file1Reader.readLine();
                String file2Line = file2Reader.readLine();

                if (file1Line != null && file2Line != null) {
                    targetFileWriter.write(lineCombiner.apply(file1Line, file2Line));
                } else if (file1Line != null) {
                    targetFileWriter.write(file1Line);
                } else if (file2Line != null) {
                    targetFileWriter.write(file2Line);
                } else {
                    areThereLinesLeftToRead = false;
                }
                targetFileWriter.newLine();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}

Here is the unit test code, for those willing to have a quick run:
package com.example.codingTest;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import java.nio.file.Path;

import static com.example.codingTest.TestUtil.*;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;


@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class FileMergerTest {

    @Autowired
    @InjectMocks 
    private FileMergerImpl fileMerger;

    /**
     * Given File1 content:
     * Line1
     * Line2
     * Line3
     * and file2 content:
     * A
     * B
     * Expect content to be
     * Line1A
     * Line2B
     * Line3
     */
    @Test
    public void givenTwoFilesAndThatFirstFileIsLongerThanSecondOneThenMergeContentIntoTarget(){
        Path sourceFile1= createPopulatedFile1(true);
        Path sourceFile2= createPopulatedFile2(false);
        Path targetFile = createEmptyFile();

        fileMerger.merge(sourceFile1,sourceFile2,targetFile, String::concat);

        assertEquals("Line1A", getContentFrom(targetFile).get(0));
        assertEquals("Line2B", getContentFrom(targetFile).get(1));
        assertEquals("Line3", getContentFrom(targetFile).get(2));

        deleteTemporaryFile(sourceFile1);
        deleteTemporaryFile(sourceFile2);
        deleteTemporaryFile(targetFile);
    }
}

package com.example.codingTest;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.util.List;

public class TestUtil {

    public static Path createPopulatedFile1(boolean isAddExtraLine)  {
        Path file1;
        BufferedWriter writer = null;
        try{
            file1 = Files.createTempFile(Path.of("./src/test/resources"),"tempfile_1", ".tmp");
           writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(file1);
                writer.write("Line1");
                writer.newLine();
                writer.write("Line2");
                writer.newLine();
                if(isAddExtraLine) {
                    writer.write("Line3");
                    writer.newLine();
                }
             writer.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return file1;
    }

    public static Path createPopulatedFile2(boolean isAddExtraLine)  {
        Path file2;
        BufferedWriter writer = null;
        try{
            file2 = Files.createTempFile(Path.of("./src/test/resources"),"tempfile_1", ".tmp");
            writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(file2);
            writer.write("A");
            writer.newLine();
            writer.write("B");
            writer.newLine();
            if(isAddExtraLine) {
                writer.write("C");
                writer.newLine();
            }
            writer.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return file2;
    }

    public static void deleteTemporaryFile(Path path){
        try {
            Files.delete(path);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public static Path createEmptyFile(){
        Path tempEmptyFile;
        try{
            tempEmptyFile = Files.createTempFile(Path.of("./src/test/resources"),"tempEmptyFile", ".tmp");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return tempEmptyFile;
    }

    public static List<String> getContentFrom(Path targetFile){
        try {
            return Files.readAllLines(targetFile);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}

Thanks in advance

The answers from this question might help. Probably needs some modification if the files have different numbers of lines.

You can obtain an Iterator for each Stream, then replace areThereLinesLeftToRead with iterator1.hasNext() && iterator2.hasNext().

Don’t use streams for this. They are not suited.

Unless you assume issues with the text encoding of the source files or the contained line breaks, the task of concatenating two files does not require processing characters nor line breaks.

See this answer for an example of how to efficiently concatenate files (without charset conversions nor line break scan operations)…

Note that the merge method in your own answer can be reduced  because you can adapt a Stream<String> into Iterable<String> for Files.write:
try(Stream<String> file1Content = Files.lines(sourceFilename1);
    Stream<String> file2Content = Files.lines(sourceFilename2)){
    
    Iterable<String> iterable = zip(file1Content, file2Content, lineCombiner)::iterator;
    Files.write(targetFilename, iterable);
}

Another way to merge streams can use Stream.iterate to generate a stream of rows from a pair of Files.lines:
Stream<String> combine(Iterator<String> a, Iterator<String> b, BinaryOperator<String> lineCombiner) {
    UnaryOperator<String> nextLine = last -> {
        String line1 = a.hasNext() ? a.next() : null;
        String line2 = b.hasNext() ? b.next() : null;
        return line1 == null ? line2 : line2 == null ? line1 : lineCombiner.apply(line1, line2);
    };
    return Stream.iterate(nextLine.apply(null), Objects::nonNull, nextLine);
}

public void merge(Path file1, Path file2, Path target, BinaryOperator<String> combiner) throws IOException {
    try(Stream<String> lines1 = Files.lines(file1);
        Stream<String> lines2 = Files.lines(file2)) {
        Iterable<String> iterable = combine(lines1.iterator(), lines2.iterator(), combiner)::iterator;
        Files.write(target, iterable);
    }
}


Thank you, @Turamarth for pointing me to the right direction.
Using only Java util libraries, a possible solution would be as follows:
package com.example.codingTest;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Spliterator;
import java.util.Spliterators;
import java.util.function.BinaryOperator;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import java.util.stream.StreamSupport;

public class FileMergerImpl {

    public void merge(Path sourceFilename1, Path sourceFilename2, Path targetFilename, BinaryOperator<String> lineCombiner) {

        try(Stream<String> file1Content = Files.lines(sourceFilename1);
            Stream<String> file2Content = Files.lines(sourceFilename2);
            BufferedWriter targetFileWriter = Files.newBufferedWriter(targetFilename)){
            Stream<String> concatenatedStream = zip(file1Content, file2Content, lineCombiner);

            concatenatedStream.forEach((lines) ->
            {
                try {
                    targetFileWriter.write(lines);
                    targetFileWriter.newLine();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            });
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    private static Stream<String> zip(Stream<String> a,
                                     Stream<String> b,
                                     BinaryOperator<java.lang.String> lineCombiner) {

        Iterator<String> aIterator = a.iterator();
        Iterator<String> bIterator = b.iterator();

        Iterator<String> cIterator = new Iterator<>() {
            @Override
            public boolean hasNext() {
                return aIterator.hasNext() || bIterator.hasNext();
            }

            @Override
            public String next() {
                String source1 = "";
                String source2 = "";
                if (aIterator.hasNext()) {
                    source1 = aIterator.next();
                }
                if (bIterator.hasNext()) {
                    source2 = bIterator.next();
                }
                return lineCombiner.apply(source1, source2);
            }
        };
        Spliterator<String> split = Spliterators.spliterator(cIterator, -1, Spliterator.SIZED);
        return StreamSupport.stream(split, false);
    }
}


As @Anonymous said, this is not a problem where the solution lies in streaming. That code is overly complex for no good reason

I agree with you, @g00se. It seems the while loop answer, without streams is more readable.
The question was asked on an interview, with a 30-minute limit. There is no way I would have come up with a streams solution in that time.
